# Driver scheduling (public transportation): enforcing 30 min break after 4 h of driving time

Tags: constraint-programming, or-tools, operations-research

We're struggling with some aspects of the following problem:

- a public transportation bus timetable consists of **shifts** (~ track sections) each with **fixed start and end times**
- **bus drivers** need to be assigned to each of those shifts
- **[constraint in question]** legal regulations demand that each bus driver has a *30 min break after 4 hours of driving* (i.e. after driving shifts)
- put differently, a driver accrues driving time when driving shifts that must not exceed 4h unless the driver takes a 30 min break in which case the accrued time is *"reset to zero"*

In summary, we need to track the accrued driving time of each driver in order to suppress shift assignments to enforce the 30 min break.

The underlying problem seems to sit halfway between a job shop and an assignment problem:

- Like **job shop problems**, it has shifts (or tasks, jobs) with many no-overlap and precedence constraints between them...
- ...**BUT** our shifts (~tasks/jobs) are not pre-assigned to drivers; in contrast with job shop problems, the tasks (~shifts) need to be executed on specific machines (~drivers) and are therefore pre-assigned, so assigning them is not part of the problem
- Like **assignment tasks**, we need to assign shifts to as few as possible drivers...
- ...**BUT** we also need to handle the aforementioned no-overlap and precedence constraints, that are not taken into account in assignment problems

So my question is, how to best model the above constraint in a **constraint problem** with the **or-tools**?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the underlying optimization problem? A routing problem? Does the model already have decision variables to keep track of timing, like arrival times at a node or something like that?

Comment: Hi Larry, classifying the underlying problem is actually our challenge. I edited the question above to make it more clear. We are currently modelling it as an assignment problem (only conceptually as pseudocode).

Comment: Post at https://or.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 1):

One general technique for specifying patterns in constraint programming is the [regular constraint](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-30201-8_36) (in [Gecode](https://www.gecode.org/doc-latest/reference/group__TaskModelIntExt.html#ga8d7535c82c78624ca3b418664391a8e2), [Choco](http://www.choco-solver.org/apidocs/org/chocosolver/solver/constraints/IIntConstraintFactory.html#regular(org.chocosolver.solver.variables.IntVar%5B%5D,org.chocosolver.solver.constraints.nary.automata.FA.IAutomaton)), [MiniZinc](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.2.3/en/lib-globals.html#extensional-constraints-table-regular-etc), among others, unsure of the status for or-tools), where patterns of variables are specified using finite automata (DFAs and NFAs) or regular expressions.

In your case, assuming that you have a sequence of variables representing what a certain driver does at each time-point, it is fairly straight-forward to specify an automaton that accepts any sequence of values that does not contain mora than four consecutive hours of driving. A sketch of such an automaton:

States:

- Driving states Dn representing n time units driving (for some resolution of time units), up to n=4 hours.
- Break states DnBm for a break of length m after n time units of driving, up to m=30 minutes.
- Start state is D0.

Transitions:

- Driving: When driving 1 unit of time, move from state Dn to D(n+1), and from a break shorter than 30 minutes from DnBm to D(n+1).
- Break of 1 unit of time, move from DnBm to DnB(m+1), unless the 30 minutes break time has been reached, for which the transition goes back to D0.
- Other actions handled mostly as self-loops, depending on desired semantics.

Of course, details will vary for your specific use-case.